# Show alert and move to next activity

Tags: android

I have included `alertdialog` in my activity.

If I click `Yes`, it should move to next activity, and if I click `No`, its should move to another.

But the `dialog` is not even appearing when I do. Here is my code. Is it possible to do like that?Can anyone help. But if I call just `finish()` when I click no, its working.

**Here is the code :**

```
            final Button submitCustomer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_customer);



        submitCustomer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                confirmRemoveOrder();

            }
        });




            private void confirmRemoveOrder() {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Confirm")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to cancel this order ?")
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        deleteOrder();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        createCustomer();
                    }
                });



    }







}
```

Comment: First of all your code is incomplete to look into . And why did you set `OnClickListener` twice on `submitCustomer` ? Its confusing . So add the proper sufficient code .

Comment: you forgot to call show method of alert dialogue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your `AlertDialog` by using below code:

**You forget to add:**

```
AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
alert.show();
```

**Create Dialog Full Code:**

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setTitle("Confirm");
dialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to cancel this order ?" );

dialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        //Action for "Yes".
        deleteOrder();
    }
})
.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        //Action for "No".
        createCustomer();
     }
 });

final AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
alert.show();
```

> Don't forget to `dismiss` dialog before going to another Activity.

**Reference :**  [AlertDialog Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html)

Comment: Just as a comment, me sure to dismiss the dialog before starting another activity since you could get memory leaks ;)

Comment: You are right @JavT, we should always dismiss dialog before going to another Activity or finish(); current Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You just fortgot to **`.show();`** method of `AlertDialog.Builder()` to display your `AlertDialog.Builder()`

change it like below

**CODE**

```
private void confirmRemoveOrder() {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Confirm")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to cancel this order ?")
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        deleteOrder();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        createCustomer();
                    }
                })
                .show();

}
```

> Also remove one of  `ClickListener` from your `submitCustomer` you have set twice clickListener to your `submitCustomer`

Answer (score 0):

To get your `AlertDialog` to display, you need to do a few more steps.

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Confirm")
        // add the rest of your setXYZ() methods here
        .create(); // this will create your AlertDialog object.
alertDialog.show(); // and this displays it!
```

Answer (score 0):

You just add .show() for your alertDialog

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Confirm")
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to cancel this order ?")
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    deleteOrder();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    createCustomer();
                }
            }).show();
```

Just adding it will fix your problem.